# C++ Merge List Elements in Pairs

Tags: c++, list, pointers, stl

I need to merge list elements in pairs, merging the first two, then the second two, and so on, and leaving the last element untouched if it has no pair. For example, if I merged the list of numbers from zero to ten by adding pairs, I would go from the top list to the bottom list below.

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

1   5   9   13  15  10
```

(The second list has extra blanks in it for readability, but its size should be six and it should not have any empty elements.)
This is a much simplified example; my actual program is using a merge function

```
void merge(Obj *a, Obj *b)
```

on a list of pointers to objects.

```
std::list<Obj*> myList;
```

How can I iterate over a list in pairs like this?

Comment: is it supposed to be homework?

Comment: This question is very unclear. You don't mean merge, you mean add. And `std::list<*Obj>` is not a valid type.

Comment: No, I'm implementing a pairing heap.
In my example with the integers, I'm adding them, but the objects need to be merged in a more complicated way with a merge function. The merge function implementation is not relevant.
I've corrected list<*Obj> to list<Obj*>.

Comment: Ah, I see ... OK I didn't get that from the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
std::list<*Obj> newList;
std::list<*Obj>::iterator itFirst = myList.begin();
std::list<*Obj>::iterator itSecond = myList.begin();
itSecond++; // move to element 1

for ( ; 
      itFirst != myList.end();
      std::advance(itFirst, 2), std::advance(itSecond, 2) )
{
    newList.push_back(merge(*itFirst, *itSecond));
}
```

This should merge each pair of consecutive elements as you showed in your example and stuff them into a new list.

Comment: That won't work for `std::lists`. They don't have random access iterators. But you can have two iterators being incremented in the loop instead.

Comment: If possible, I'd prefer to keep using a list, since I add and remove elements frequently. Unfortunately, lists don't have efficient random access.

Comment: @juanchopanza Should I increment both iterators twice in each loop after the merge to move to the next pair, or do I increment less because of the merge?

Comment: @Qaz if you wanted to run double iterators, you would start one at begin() then the next at begin()++, then iterate each one in steps of 2. The first will grab 0, 2, 4, etc and the second will grab 1, 3, 5